# Pointers and arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, functional-programming

Can any one explain what does the following code do? As per my knowledge this program converts the number to the given base but I can't understand how it is done?

```
#include<stdio.h>
char *fun(unsigned int num, int base);

int main()
{
    char *s;
    s=fun(128, 2);
    s=fun(128, 16);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
char *fun(unsigned int num, int base)
{
    static char buff[33];
    char *ptr = &buff[sizeof(buff)-1];
    *ptr = '\0';
    do
    {
        *--ptr = "0123456789abcdef"[num %base];
        num /=base;
    }while(num!=0);
    return ptr;
}
```

What does this line `*--ptr = "0123456789abcdef"[num %base];` in the above code means?

Answer (score 1):

I think your *main* confusion lies in the statement

```
"0123456789abcdef"[num %base];
```

Well, this can be rewritten as a combination of

```
char arr[] = "0123456789abcdef";
```

and

```
 arr[num %base];
```

Other than that, `*--ptr =` can be broken down to

```
 --ptr;
 *ptr = <some value>;
```

---

As far as the program logic in considered, you're quite right and the digit is chosen by using the `[num %base]` position from the `array` holding the digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can split `*--ptr = "0123456789abcdef"[num %base];` into several separate statements so it becomes more clear:

`*ptr=` is the same as `ptr[0]=`, i.e. it stores some value at location 0 of the memory where `ptr` is poiinting to. (End of the `buff` during the first loop iteration)

`--ptr` decreases the value of `ptr` by 1 (after it is used). So it points to to the previous (second last) location of `buff`.

Combined, `*--ptr =` first sets the value of `ptr[0]` and then decreases the pointer.

Next, `"0123456789abcdef"` char(acter) array, so `"0123456789abcdef"[...]` gets a value from the array of chars at the specified index.

The used index `num % base' calculates the remainder after dividing`num`by`base`

So combined the complete line grabs a value from the char array (at index `num % base`), stores it at the location where `ptr` it pointing to and decreases `ptr` (i.e. the points the the previous memory location)

---

About the actual working of the application: What this is doing is checking the remainder of `num` (for the given `base`) and grabs the correct (char)-value from the string (i.e. gets the representing number). Next, it divides the number by its base, in order to be able to determine the next remainder, and so on.

This would result in the representation being reversed (reading to right to left), so the buffer is written from the back to the start (hence the `--ptr` part, instead of `++ptr`).

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is a pointer that holds memory address of a `char` variable.

`--ptr` simply decrements the pointer (now it'll point to the previous object of the same type). `*` is simply accessing the value.

```
"0123456789abcdef"[num %base]
```

will return the char at the position `num % base`.

Answer (score 0):

My analysis is as follows after googling in net.

Firstly, "0123456789abcdef" is used to pick values if it is decimal values are picked from 0-9, if it is octal values are picked from 0 to 7, if it is hexa decimal values are picked from 0-f, if it is binary only between 0 and 1.

Simple "0123456789abcdef" can be treated as character array i.e. char a[] = "0123456789abcdef";
and "0123456789abcdef"[num % base] means a[num % base]. Each time the the number given is divided with base the character is picked up from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here *--ptr is decrement the one position in a array and pointing to one place.

So when you are using that `"0123456789abcdef"[num %base]`. answer of `num % base` is giving
one output. Take that is two. So it will return the character that is placed on the second place.

So based on the answer of `num % base` is storing the value in the given string.